# How to draw AdMob onto a canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, admob

I am having a problem getting AdMob to show up onto my canvas.

My code is shown below.

```
layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    adView = new AdView((Activity) getContext(), AdSize.BANNER, "############");
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    layout.addView(adView);
    TextView textView = new TextView(context); 
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setText("Hello world");
    layout.addView(textView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

In my onDraw method I have.

```
 canvas.drawColor(Color.GRAY);  
 layout.measure(getWidth(), getHeight());
 layout.layout(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            layout.draw(canvas);
```

"Hello World" shows up but not the Ad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the 'hello world' was for testing?

Have you tried calling `adView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));` ?

When you call addView on a viewgroup, by default the child inherits the layoutparams of the parent, and since in your case the parent layoutparams are wrap_content then it might be shrinking the adview to be non visible.

Also, you shouldn't call layout.measure in your onDraw, you should probably do it in the onMeasure method.

Comment: I have tried Match_Parent and Fill_Parent with no luck.  If i change the background color of the layout to black the whole screen turns black so I know there is space.  The ads are turning up in the log cat as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not solved this already: get rid of the Hello World TextView or declare it before

```
adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
layout.addView(adView);
```